# WCF accessible via HTTP request with querystrings as parameters

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to create a WCF that can be invoked via a HTTP request and takes parameters in the URL.

Like:
`http://someservice.svc/FetchEverything?User=xxx&category=clothes`

The service should then return json in the response.

Would be thankful for advice.

Comment: Basically nothing. Doing some experimenting with [WebGet] on methods. But can't figure out how to call them

Comment: Did you mean to write `http://someservice.svc/FetchEverything?User=xxx&category=clothes` ?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I meant to write. Edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at WCF Data Services. This allows you to easily expose an Entity Framework model (or part thereof) using a REST interface, or more precisely, an OData interface (= REST + AtomPub + query support).

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668794.aspx.